# tools:showIn="navigation_view" not working for making menu

Tags: android, menu, menubar, navigationview

I need help. I tried to build a drawbar menu in Android Studio. also, there is no icon is working there.

[[view of the design tab]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ4Ak.png)

These are the code I used in the drawer_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/Beranda"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bmi"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bmi"
        android:title="@string/Kalkulator_BMI"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_statistic"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_data"
        android:title="@string/Statistik"></item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_news"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_news"
        android:title="@string/Kabar_Terkini"></item>
</group>
<item android:title="@string/Pengaturan_Bantuan">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"
            android:title="@string/Pengaturan"></item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
            android:title="@string/Bantuan"></item>
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: There is no flaw in above code. error might be in other part of your code.

Comment: the error might be in your java code

Answer (score 0):

This is render problem in my case :

Please upgrade your library to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```